# What's up with Plouffe's inverter? Is there an alternative?

Tags: online-resources

For quite some time now (at least a year), whenever I tried to use [Plouffe's inverter](http://pi.lacim.uqam.ca), the request timed out, but there's no indication either on the site itself or on the Web that it's out of service or having problems. Does anyone know whether it's still online? Have I just been extremely unlucky?

Also, if it really is offline or practically unusable, do you know of any alternatives? I know [OEIS](https://oeis.org), but that's for integer sequences, and its use for decimal representations of real numbers feels a bit unnatural (though it has quite a few [sequences of that kind](https://oeis.org/search?q=7,2,9,9,5&sort=&language=english&go=Search)).

Comment: Wolfram Alpha...

Comment: @Hans: Cool, I didn't know it does that :-)

Comment: About 2 weeks ago, seeing such matters, I succeeded to find a substitute on the Internet. It worked fine. Now I'm trying to track it down again -- and I can't! I did not remember that working URL, because I thought the flaw at the original site was temporary. If I find the working software again, I'll share the URL with you.

Comment: Heh. I guess you've cleared your cache since then?

Comment: Additional Resources : [RIES](http://mrob.com/pub/ries/), [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=closed%20form%201.4142135), the ['old' ISC](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try one of these:

- [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html)
- [Inverse Symbolic Calculator Plus](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/)

Comment: Great, thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: From the ISC+ site: `The lookup tables include a substantial data set compiled by S. Plouffe both before and during his period as an employee at CECM.` So it seems to be the legitimate successor to Plouffe's inverter.

Comment: The first link is dead, the second says it is down for maintanence indefinitely.

Comment: @user14717, fixed, thanks for reporting

Comment: Now the second one is down, but the first one still works.

Answer (score 6):

I am told that the server it used to run on at UQAM doesn't exist anymore, and there are no plans to revive it there.

Edited to add: in response to a suggestion from me, the former Plouffe's Inverter site now admits that the Inverter no longer exists, and redirects users to the Inverse Symbolic Calculator Plus mentioned in the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that all the referenced websites are down, at least for the moment. However, I just noticed the following on Simon Plouffe's [website](http://plouffe.fr/):

> 2016 : Portable version of the Plouffe Inverter : Version portable de l'Inverseur de Plouffe. 3 billion entries at 32 digits precision.

This portable version can be accessed [here](http://plouffe.fr/ipgz/).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But this seems to be just a set of directories with lots of text files with numbers in them. So I'd say it's not really a portable version of the inverter, just a data set that you can use to build your own inverter.

Comment: @joriki Sure, but notice that the data is sorted by the associated real number, so it shouldn't be hard to look for expressions if you only need to make one or two queries. But anyway, it seems like isc+ is up!

Comment: The link to the software is dead.