# Reverse engineer numerical results to fractions of remarkable numbers?

Tags: numerical-methods, fractions

Numerical methods output decimal numbers that oftentimes result from the division of two (or more) numbers:

- $1.5708... = \frac{\pi}{2}$
- $0.3679... = \frac{1}{e}$
- $0.7071... = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$
- $0.7501315 ... = \frac{{e}^{\frac{\pi}{12}}}{\sqrt{3}}$ (maybe this one is pushing it a little)

What is a good way to "reverse engineer" a decimal point number to the fraction it **might** have originated from?

Of course, maintaining a lookup table of values for most commonly encountered decimal numbers and their fractions of "remarkable numbers" is feasible to some extent, but is there a better way?

Side question: what is the proper jargon to succinctly describe this problem?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219991.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is useful: `(the inverter) uses a combination of lookup tables and integer relation algorithms in order to associate a closed form representation with a user-defined, truncated decimal expansion (written as a floating point expression)` ... Are there other "better" ways?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question!  It's an applied problem for me, but I need a formula or shorthand referencing an algorithmic function.  Let's say I want to make a rectangular Sudoku gameboard in 5 dimensions, and I want it to be (9x7x8x6x5) I need a function that identifies the fraction that produces .97865, or any other fraction.

Comment: If have a small collection of percents you know are rounded rational fractions that share a denominator (e.g. some one gave you a pie chart with percents, but no `n`), then you can look for an approximate LCD between the decimals, and the denominator will be it's approximate inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy with just a Python library, take a look at the [identify() function of mpmath](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/identification.html) and its documentation.
Its source is available at [mpath](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath)'s [`identification.py`](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/blob/master/mpmath/identification.py) and refers to [Ferguson's PSLQ Integer Relation Algorithm](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/bailey/paper/html/node3.html) (the [paper](https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/pslq.pdf) is available online).

Comment: cool, thank you, I'll take a look. Are you the author of the mpmath library @JohanC?

Comment: @Reblochon Masque. No, at the moment I'm not involved with mathmp, but it is an intriguing topic .

Comment: Thank you - It is the similarity between your name ( @JohanC ) & that of the of the repo maintainer (Johansson), that made me ask. I'll review the lib shortly, and if it answers my request, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's too hard to give a method of reverse engineering decimal notations of all sorts of definable numbers so I will give just a method on how to do so for all rational numbers, with your brain alone not using Python. Given any rational number expressed in decimal notation ending with a line over a string of digits to indicate that that string of digits starts repeating for ever from then on, let's call $m$ the number of digits in the written notation after the decimal point and before the overline and $n$ the number of digits with an overline in the notation. To determine its mixed fraction notation, first you have to recognize that the number is a multiple of $\frac{1}{10^m \times (10^n - 1)}$. Let $p$ be the number the string of digits after the decimal point but before the overline represents and $q$ be the number the string of digits with the overline represents. Then the real part of the given number is $\frac{(p \times (10^n - 1)) + q}{10^m \times (10^n - 1)}$. There's an easy way to compute the greatest common factor of the numerator and denominator of that expression then divide the numerator and denominator by the greatest common factor to reduce it to lowest terms.